# Sufficiently transitive implies alternating sans Enormous Theorem

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions, simple-groups

According to [this webpage](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~laci/reu03/n2_11/node1.html#thm:no-6-transitive) and [this mathworld article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TransitiveGroup.html), if $G<S_n$ is a permutation group which acts sextuply transitively then $G=A_n$ is the alternating group, but this fact is known on the basis of the classification of finite simple groups. Is there any $k$ for which we know that $k$-transitive implies alternating *without* assumption of the enormous theorem, or any other advanced technology?

One could also ask about $(n-r)$-transitive groups of degree $n$ for fixed $r$. In particular, $r=1$ yields only symmetric groups, and a counting argument with $r=2$ yields only symmetric and alternating groups. The next stage would be to ask, can we prove $(n-3)$-transitive groups of degree $n$ are symmetric or alternating with only finitely many exceptions without invoking the enormous theorem?

Comment: The answer is no!